# Drop/replace access method?

Tags: postgresql

As of PostgresSQL 9.6, [access methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-create-access-method.html) were introduced for core functionality. I have been making some modifications to PostgreSQL and I would like to recreate an access method- but there is nothing like CREATE OR REPLACE so I wanted to perform DROP ACCESS METHOD btree; and then create it again.

But I am presented with:

> ERROR:  cannot drop access method btree because it is required by the database system

Maybe I can drop this restriction since I am planning to create it again? How can I achieve my goal?

UPDATE: I suppose something interesting would be to create the same access method under a different name - but then how can I be sure that this is being used over the other is not clear to me.

Comment: I think the point here is the same as with UDTs: you can define (and use) your own, custom, user-defined types, but you cannot replace the implementation behind `character varying` f.ex. -- If you could do that, half of the documentation would become obsolete. If you think, you can write a better implementation to `btree`, that's nice. Play around with it. Use it. You can even create a pull request for your code (as PostgreSQL is open source) so everyone could benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to drop `btree`, and fortunately the system keeps you from doing so.

If you want to write a substitute for it, that's fine. Add it as a new access method and use it throughout. The presence of `btree` won't bother you or slow you down.

As pozs said, if you think you can improve PostgreSQL's B-tree implementation so that it would be a benefit for everybody, get in touch with pgsql-hackers.